# Using addition in Lua without using the result

Tags: lua

I'm trying to run the following in Lua 5.3

```lua
function new_t()
  local self = {}
  setmetatable(self, {
    __add = function(lhs,rhs)
        print('ok so',lhs,'+',rhs)
    end
  })
  return self 
end

local t1 = new_t()
local t2 = new_t()

t1 + t2
```

I get an error saying `syntax error near '+'`. However if I change the last line to `x = t1 + t2`, it runs and prints without error.

Is it possible to use a binary operator without using the resulting value? Why doesn't Lua let me do `t1 + t2` or even `1 + 2` by itself?

Comment: Just got done writing my answer, and I got curious: Do you really intend to print something in `__add`, or is that some kind of temporary testing thing?

Comment: @luther temporary testing! I'd like to use this addition operation as just a convenient way to modify the lhs table. For instance, instead of `t1:add(t2)`, I want to try `t1 + t2`.

Comment: I should've asked that to begin with. I've edited my answer.

Comment: You could do  `print( t1 + t2 )`  or  `t1 = t1 + t2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua doesn't allow this, because all the operators (except function calls) are intended to always calculate a result. There's no good reason to throw away the result of an expression, and it usually indicates a coding mistake.

If you just want to test your code, I suggest using `assert`:

```
assert(not (t1 + t2))
```

I use `not` here, because your `__add` function doesn't return anything.

EDIT: Normally, when we add two numbers, we expect to get a new number, without changing the original numbers. Lua's metamethods are designed to work the same way. To do side-effects like printing or modifying an operand, it's easier and clearer to use a regular named method.

Comment: `local _ = t1 + t2` would be better.